# Listing all the files on the server using C

Tags: c, apache

I am really new to C and especially with socket programming so basically I have setup apache server on my local machine where I am hosting multiple audio/video/txt files.

Now I want to display those files using C. (just like ls -l in linux but it should be from the server)

I am able to fetch the html content of local server but that is something not I am looking for.

Here is my code for getting html content from the localhost

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 

int main()
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[6000];

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

  
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.3"); // localhost ip
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );




    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    //Send some data
    message = "GET /?st=1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.3\r\n\r\n";
    if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if( recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 6000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }
    puts("Reply received\n");
    puts(server_reply);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: Are you trying to run this application on "Server A" and get a listing of files on "Server B"?

--
Thanks for the update to that.

Here is the problem, you are not going to be able to get a directory listing from one server to the other just by sending a standard http request.  You will need a reciprocal application on "Server B".  Do you have direct access to that server, or is this a public server and you are trying to mirror it?

Comment: I'll run this from the client and get the file listings from the server.

Comment: FYI  - comments like this go under "comments", not answers.

Comment: @brian - I know and I'm sorry, but this system is so stupid it will not allow a comment if you do not have enough cred.  I can probably answer this guys question but needed more information. :)

Comment: Yes I have a direct access to the server. So you mean to say I have to create another server B to get listings of server A files?

Comment: Let's say you have 5 files on "Server A" (1.txt, 2.txt, etc).  If you are on your client (or we can call it "Server B") where your c application is running, you cannot directly talk to Server A via a standard http request and ask it for a list of its files.  That would be a big security risk.

You could however have an application (cgi in c, perl, php, etc) on the webserver and send an http request asking for files.